# Grassmann variables

Tags: fermions, grassmann-numbers

In lots of QFT and SUSY texts they give you the basic properties of left and right handed Weyl spinors, $\psi$ and $\bar{\chi}$. They state that the components of these objects, $\psi^a$ and $\bar{\chi}_{\dot{a}}$ respectively, are [Grassmann variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number) which anti-commute with each other. So we have

$$\psi^a\psi^b=-\psi^b\psi^a$$ and $$\bar{\chi}_{\dot{a}}\bar{\chi}_{\dot{b}}=-\bar{\chi}_{\dot{b}}\bar{\chi}_{\dot{a}}$$

But what about something like $$\bar{\chi}_{\dot{a}}\psi^a=\varepsilon^{ac}\bar{\chi}_{\dot{a}}\psi_c~?$$ Is this equal to $$-\varepsilon^{ac}\psi_c\bar{\chi}_{\dot{a}}~?$$

I'd imagine it's true, since at the end of the day both $\psi_c$ and $\bar{\chi}_{\dot{a}}$ are anticommuting objects, and the representation of the Lorentz group they transform under shouldn't have anything to do with that.

Comment: That quantity does not make sense. The epsilon symbol can only contract dotted indices with each other or undotted indices with each other. If you wish to contract dotted indices with un-dotted ones then you need to use sigma matrices.

Comment: @Prahar Where have I contracted dotted with undotted indicies?

Comment: Sorry! I mis-spoke. I got confused with you using the same letter $a$ for both the dotted and un-dotted index.

Comment: BTW, the answer to your question is "Yes".